# Safari switching inputs on user input

Tags: html, reactjs, safari, mobile-safari

I have an app built in react, there are 2 user inputs that the user needs to fill in, the user types into the first input and it will then switch the input with the second input and the value will be updated in this input instead of the first input as I would expect.

In chrome/Firefox this works correctly, only safari has this issue.

This can be seen here by opening the Maße section and then typing into this inputs - http://plissee.test.impulsfaktor.net/konfigurator?params=%7B%22designation%22%3A4%7D

Any ideas why this is happening only in safari?